# Rename Save button to Submit in Modern Ui NewformAspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, button

i am trying to change button name from Save to Submit using extension but its not working below is my code

```
let newbutton: any = document.getElementsByClassName("ReactClientFormSection")[1] || document.documentElement;  
//debugger;
newbutton.style.display='none';
let newbutton2: any = document.getElementsByClassName("ReactFieldEditor")[13] || document.documentElement;  
newbutton2.style.display='none';
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("ReactClientForm-editButtons");  
//Get the "Save" button  
for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)  
{  
if(inputs[i].innerHTML == "button" && inputs[i].innerHTML == "Save")  
{  
//Change the "Save" button's Text to "Submit"  
inputs[i].innerHTML = "Submit";  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inputs[i].innerHTML cannot be equal to two values at the same time.
[image]

You could change the class to ms-Button--primary.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Button--primary")[0].innerText
```

[image]

Updated:
[image]

Comment: i tried but unable to write in code how to change value

Comment: How do you add the code into moden page?As I test ,it could use document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Button--primary")[0].innerText="test" change the button text.

Comment: yes is working i making sill mistake my bad , many thanks